# Flutter: how to run a function when iframe code changes without changing url?

Tags: flutter, dart, iframe, webview

I am using webview_flutter package. I want to execute a dart function when the codes in iframe changes without changing url.

**Note**: The url has CORS policy enabled, so I can't use javascript channels / modify iframe contents.

So, how can I execute a function whenever the code in iframe changes ?

Please help me..

Answer (score -1):

I think may be you can take screenshots of current iframe and use image comparison tool to detect if the specific content appear in your iframe.

*(You should check any other alteratives first because, it would be too complicated and a bad way of coding. Also this idea may not always work)*